# Create CMake Qt project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cmake

So basically I want to write a GUI application using Qt framework. I also need to make it possible to work on this project under Linux, so I thought about CMake, which would automate a lot of things for me.

My main editor on Windows is Visual Studio 2017, so I've installed Qt VS plugin, so when I want to create a new project I have 2 options to choose: new CMake project or new Qt GUI application project. This confuses me a little bit, cuz I know that Qt enforces `qmake` by default.

So my question is: How do I create Qt GUI application project in Visual Studio, which would use CMake as a build system? (so do I choose CMake and add Qt to it, or do I choose Qt GUI application and then somehow add CMake to it?)

Comment: If you want to use CMake and Qt then you can refer to [this documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/cmake-manual.html). It is advisable to first write your `CMakeLists.txt` on your own. Then in Visual Studio you can import your CMake project. But if you want to try to force Visual Studio to make a CMake file for you (I don't know if that is possible) then you should choose CMake and add Qt to it.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal setup you need if you want to see a window is following:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
add_executable(window main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(window Qt5::Widgets)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget window;
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

It is not tied to windows or linux and should run almost everywhere.

But then you will most probably need more Qt feature. So the logical steps would be to enable [`AUTOMOC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_AUTOMOC.html) and enable [`CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR.html) as the [manual](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/cmake-manual.html) referenced by Amit Singh says.