# Creating a QT Project with CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am trying to set up a QT project with CMake (and not using QT Creator).
I am currently trying to build a minimum working example, that just shows an empty window. My current code is based (more like coppied) from [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-get-started.html#building-a-c-gui-application) tutorial from the official (?) docs and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436877/create-cmake-qt-project-in-visual-studio-2017) answer by another user to a similar question.

I then run the following three commands:

```
cmake .
cmake --build .
.\Debug\helloworld.exe
```

But nothing happens (when running the program, the first two commands appear to work as intended). If I put the code from main.cpp into an existing QT Creator project it works and shows an empty window. Anyone can tell me, what I am missing?

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    //Option 1, like in the mentioned stackoverflow answer
    //QWidget window;

    //Option 2, to test If maybe the QWidget above was the problem
    QMainWindow window;
    window.setWindowTitle("Test");

    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(helloworld VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Without this line, cmake does not find the package
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/6.3.1/msvc2019_64")

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
qt_standard_project_setup()


add_executable(helloworld
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(helloworld PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets)

set_target_properties(helloworld PROPERTIES
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE ON
    MACOSX_BUNDLE ON
)
```

**EDIT:**
As suggested by Aamir I created an extra build folder. The output of the three comands is as follows:

One more thing, if I replace the code in main.cpp with a simple "Hello World" programm, it works fine. I therefore assumed, that the missing/failed parts in the first cmake command are no problem. Or am I wrong about that part?

```
PS H:\Coding\QT_Tic_Tac_toe> mkdir build


    Directory: H:\Coding\QT_Tic_Tac_toe


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        19/08/2022     10:11                build


PS H:\Coding\QT_Tic_Tac_toe> cd .\build\
PS H:\Coding\QT_Tic_Tac_toe\build> cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.32.31332.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC
-- Performing Test HAVE_STDATOMIC - Success
-- Found WrapAtomic: TRUE
-- Could NOT find WrapVulkanHeaders (missing: Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: H:/Coding/QT_Tic_Tac_toe/build
PS H:\Coding\QT_Tic_Tac_toe\build> cmake --build .
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.1+52cd2da31 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Checking Build System
  Automatic MOC and UIC for target helloworld
  Building Custom Rule H:/Coding/QT_Tic_Tac_toe/CMakeLists.txt
  mocs_compilation_Debug.cpp
  main.cpp
  Generating Code...
  helloworld.vcxproj -> H:\Coding\QT_Tic_Tac_toe\build\Debug\helloworld.exe
  Building Custom Rule H:/Coding/QT_Tic_Tac_toe/CMakeLists.txt
PS H:\Coding\QT_Tic_Tac_toe\build> .\Debug\helloworld.exe
PS H:\Coding\QT_Tic_Tac_toe\build>
```

Comment: Please show the output of `cmake --build` command. CMake best practice is to create a separate folder for all the build artefacts instead of build in the same folder as source code.  Insstructions for building in a separate folder: `mkdir build` , `cd build` `cmake ..`

Comment: Do you have added the directory that contains the Qt DLLs to your `PATH`? E.g by calling `set PATH=C:\Qt\6.3.1\msvc2019_64\bin;%PATH%` in your console before running the program.

Comment: That did it! I though I added the directory to PATH when instaling QT, but apparently I did not. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Qt DLL directory to the `PATH` environment variable either permanently or before calling the program from the console as follows:

```
set PATH=C:\Qt\6.3.1\msvc2019_64\bin;%PATH%
```

If you would have started your application from a `cmd` console window an error dialog would have popped up notifying you about the missing DLL. But as you were using `PowerShell` there is a bug pending (see [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17060)) that prevents the error dialog to be shown.

NB: You can call `cmd` from a `PowerShell` window to get the old console window.